# Solve non-linear differential equation with boundary conditions

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider this problem with a differential equation and border conditions. I have to find a differentiable function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that it will satisfy the following conditions: $$f(0)=a,f(1)=b,\ddot f=\dfrac{\dot f^2-c^2f^4}{f}$$
with $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$ given.

Differential equations are really not my field and I really don't know how to find this function $f$ (in particular how to solve this differential equation), so I hope someone will point me out a way to proceed.

As I said in the comments this problem arises from riemannian geometry: these are the conditions that a component of a geodesic must satisfy.

I've tried to solve the differential equation imposing $v:=\dot f$. In this way I get

$$\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial f}v=\dfrac{v^2-c^2f^4}{f}$$
but this isn't an ordinary separable differential equation and unfortunately I don't know how to proceed.

Thank you.

EDIT: user zwim found a solution $f=\frac{k}{c\cdot ch(kx+\phi)}$ which checks out. My question now is: **how can I be sure that there aren't other solutions?** If there are other solutions, which are they?

Comment: the solution looks very ugly

Comment: Where is this equation from?

Comment: it's from the geodesic equation of a riemannian metric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let try another change

$u=1/cf$.

$u'=-f'/cf^2$

$u''=2f'^2/cf^3-f''/cf^2=(2f'^2-ff'')/cf^3$

Thus we get : $uu''-u'^2=(2f'^2-ff'')/c^2f^4-f'^2/c^2f^4=(f'^2-ff'')/c^2f^4=1$.

The new equation is $$uu''-u'^2=1$$

According to this link : [How to solve $1+y'^2=yy''$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040971/how-to-solve-1y2-yy)

If we derivate this and integrate we get $u=Ae^{kx}+Be^{-kx}$.

Let's report in the initial equation [...] and I get $4ABk^2=1$, let's call $\lambda=2Ak$ which is arbitrary.

We get $u=\frac{1}{2k}(\lambda e^{kx}+\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-kx})$

And finally $f=\frac{2k}{c\space(\lambda e^{kx}+\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-kx})}$

**Note:** there is a lot of questionnable stuff done in the way $u$ is solved, so we may have miss some solutions, but at least since we reported in the initial equation these we found, we are sure that what we found is at least correct.

**Addendum Jan 02:**

The substitution $u=1/cf$ does not pose problem, since there is already $f$ at denominator in original expression. The only delicate thing there is, comes from the resolution of $uu′′−u′^2=1$ because we derivate (assuming $u$ is 3 times derivable). We also divide by $uu′′$ but this is not an issue because $uu′′=1+u′^2>0$.

As stated by Han.d.Bruijn we then get a linear ODE so unicity theorem applies.

Yet $u''$ has an expression that depends only of $f,f',f''$ so $u'''$ exists if $f'''$ exists, but $f''$ itself has an expression that depends only from $f,f'$ so we can carry on the derivation. By the same process if one supposes $f$ is $C^1$ then it becomes automatically $C^\infty$ and so does $u$. Consequently we can be quite confident that we found all solutions at least $C^1$ and which do not annulate.

Comment: I just realized that this is equivalent to $\frac{k}{c\space ch(kx+\phi)}$ with $\phi=\ln\lambda$.

Comment: well $\pm k$ to take into account $\lambda<0$

Comment: thank you! But how can I be sure that there aren't other solutions?

Comment: C@User29983: If you follow the link in this (+1) answer, you will arrive at an answer that ends with a _linear_ ODE. And user zwim has just employed the solution of that ODE, which is pretty complete, I suppose. (It's a catenary, btw)

Comment: yes I understand, but my concern is about the substitution $u=1/cf$ and the steps before $uu''-u'^2=1$

Comment: @User29983: The ODE as formulated by yourself already says that $f \ne 0$ , right? What else can go wrong?